# How to use a regular expression with preg_match_all to split a string into blocks following a pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm going to be working with a long string of data that is serialized into blocks using a pattern (x:y).

However, I struggle with regular expressions, and are looking for resources to help identify how to construct a regex to identify any/all of these blocks as they appear in a string.

For example, given the following string:

```
$s = 't:user c:red t:admin n:"bob doe" s:expressionsf:json';
```

> Note: the f:json at the end is missing a space on purpose, because the format might vary with how the string is eventually given to me. Each block might be spaced, and they might not.

How would I identify each block of x:y to end with the below result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => t:user
    [1] => c:red
    [2] => t:admin
    [3] => n:"bob doe"
    [4] => s:expression
    [5] => f:json
)
```

I've tested various expressions using my limited knowledge, but have not been terribly successful.

I can successfully match the pattern using something like this:

> ^[ctrns]:.+

But this unfourtunately matches the entire string. The part I seem to be missing is how to break each block, while also maintaining the ability to keep spaces within the pairs (see n:"bob doe" example).

Any assistance would be super appreciated! Also, ideally any submission would be explained as to what each token in the expression was accomplishing so that I better my understanding of these techniques.

I've been using https://regexr.com/ to practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
[ctnsf]:(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\S+?(?=[ctnsf]:|\s|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5dNQH/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[ctnsf]:`: Match one of `ctnsf` characters followed by `:`
- `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`: Match a quoted substring. This takes care of escaped quotes as well.
- `|`: OR
- `\S+?`: Match 1+ not-whitespace characters (non-greedy)
- `(?=[ctnsf]:|\s|$)`: Positive lookahead to assert one of the conditions given in assertions.

**Code:**

```
$re = '/[ctnsf]:(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|\S+?(?=[ctnsf]:|\s|$))/m';
$str = 't:user c:red t:admin n:"bob \\"doe" s:expressionsf:json';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/1113872)

Comment: This is great, thank you.  One limitation of this answer however is that it does not correctly evaluate:

> $s = 't:user c:red t:admin n:"bob doe" **s:expressionsf:json'**;
As two matches.

Is this even possible?

Comment: @anubhava it's definitely working in your example and in another site I've tested it in, but preg_match_all is complaining:

preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 54

Using the following call: preg_match_all('/[ctnsf]:(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\S+?(?=[ctnsf]:|\s|$))/', 't:user c:red t:admin n:"bob doe" s:expressionsf:json', $a);